# Get pseudo content with javascript in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I'm trying to get Jeremy Keiths Breakpoint checking to work in IE8. His solution looks like this.

```
var size = window.getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').getPropertyValue('content');
```

I'm trying to achive the same with JQuery. This is what ive got. It doesn't work at all but it illustrates what i'm after.

```
var size = $('body:after').css('content');
```

And this is my CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
body:after {
    content: 'min960px';
    display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: `$('body:after')` is not working?

Comment: Why? Afaik IE8 doesn't have a support for `:after` or media queries.

Comment: And jQuery doesn't support pseudo selectors.

Comment: @Teemu - IE8 *does* support `:after`. You're right about media queries, though.

Comment: Yes! No, IE8 does not support Media Queries. I'm using respond.js but that almost only support max-width and min width. Thanks!

Comment: If someone would put together these comments into an answer i'd mark it as the solution. Clearly I'm on the wrong track using this technique and supporting IE8 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can not acces to content by JavaScript!